# Trouble loading data into a newly installed QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have just installed QGIS 2.16 onto a laptop running Windows 10.

However, I'm having trouble loading any data into the program which crashes everytime I do this with the error message:

qgis-bin.exe has stopped working

Any ideas on why this is occurring?

Comment: There is not enough information in this description to come up with an answer. Have you tried installing a different version? Do you use the stand-alone installer or OSGeo4W?

Comment: I had used the stand-alone installer. I tried installing 2.14 this morning and it has no issues loading in data, so resolved for now!